# How to deploy an ASP.Net docker containerized application to an On-Premise Server, using Azure CI-CD Pipelines?

Tags: docker-compose, azure-devops

I have a multi-layer Asp.Net Application running. Due to it's multi-layer nature, I have to build a container for it and deploy it as a container.

Is there anyway I can deploy it to an existing server using Azure-Pipelines?

All other support that I am finding online is related to deploying to Azure App Services, however I would like to deploy to an existing production environment.

Comment: Please check this [article](https://www.anupams.net/deploy-to-on-premise-devops/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there anyway I can deploy it to an existing server using Azure-Pipelines?

Since you are deploying to the local environment, you can use [Self-hosted Agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install)(Build Pipeline and Release Pipeline) or [Deployment Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deployment-groups/?view=azure-devops)(Release Pipeline).

Then you could try the following pipeline settings.

[image]

Here is a blog about [ASP.Net Application Deployment in Docker for Windows](https://blogs.perficient.com/2017/08/24/asp-net-application-deployment-in-docker-for-windows/).

You could use `Command Line Task` to run the docker command. In this case, you can move the local build and deploy process to azure devops

By the way, if you have the [Container registry Service connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#sep-docreg) in Azure Devops, you could use the  [Docker task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/docker?view=azure-devops) or [Docker Compose task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/docker-compose?view=azure-devops).

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback, it helps a lot.I will give it a try and let you know how it goes

Comment: Great. Feel free to let me know your progress.Hope it can meet your needs.

Comment: Oh yes Kevin, this is gold, I am waiting for my to team to finalize the process so I can take it Azure and start the process.